# Getting user input to copy from a TableViewController to a ViewController using Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, input, uiviewcontroller

I'm working on an app in which the user inputs three values (artist, album and release date). I'm trying to get those user entered values to 'copy' over to another TableViewController.

The values show on this, the FreshReleaseTableViewController (the code below) and I need them to copy to EditFreshReleaseViewController.

How would I go about this?

```
 import UIKit
 import CoreData
 import UserNotifications

 class FreshReleaseTableViewController: UITableViewController{

var freshreleases = [Release_Date]()

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //create a new button
    let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    //set image for button
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Mic App Logo.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none

}

@objc func editAction() {
    let viewController = AddfreshreleaseViewController()
    navigationController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = Release_Date.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Release_Date>

    let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "artist", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "album", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2]
    do {
        freshreleases = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error {
        print("Could not fetch because of error: \(error).")
    }

    /*let startOfToday = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()) as NSDate
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "release_date > %@", startOfToday)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate*/

    NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>()

    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isReleased = NO")

    tableView.reloadData()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return freshreleases.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FreshReleaseCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    let freshrelease = freshreleases[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

    let artist = freshrelease.artist ?? ""
    let album = freshrelease.album ?? ""
    cell.textLabel?.text = artist + "'s\nnew album '" + album + "'\nreleases"

    if let date = freshrelease.release_date as Date? {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    } else {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
    }

    return cell
}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if freshreleases.count > indexPath.row {
        let freshrelease = freshreleases[indexPath.row]

        // Remove notification
        if let identifier = freshrelease.release_dateId {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [identifier])
        }

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        context.delete(freshrelease)
        freshreleases.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error {
            print("Could not save \(error)")
        }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?

{
    let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Edit", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Update action ...")
        let MainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let vc : UIViewController = MainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FreshReleaseEdit") as UIViewController
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        success(true)

    })
    modifyAction.title = "Edit"
    modifyAction.backgroundColor = .blue

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])
}

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

}
*/

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `EditFreshReleaseViewController` variable which represents selected fresh release

```
var selectedFreshRelease: Release_Date?
```

now in line where you're declaring view controller which is gonna be presented, downcast this controller as `EditFreshReleaseViewController`

```
let vc = MainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FreshReleaseEdit") as! EditFreshReleaseViewController
```

then just assign its variable as item from `freshReleases` array on index `indexPath.row`

```
vc.selectedFreshRelease = self.freshReleases[indexPath.row]
```

finally, present this view controller as you do

```
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. I'm a little confused as to where to place these lines of code within the FreshReleaseTableViewController.

Comment: Inside moduly action in leading swipe actions configuration

Comment: I think I figured it out but when I push the edit button it crashes the app with the below error message

Comment: Permission for notifications granted!
Update action ...
Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1d37e81e0) to 'fresh_release.EditfreshreleaseViewController' (0x1042b7248).
2018-12-16 22:41:53.378806-0500 fresh release[6927:1758562] Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1d37e81e0) to 'fresh_release.EditfreshreleaseViewController' (0x1042b7248).
(lldb)